# Are there more methods for the "application" object?

Tags: excel, office-js, onenote

Am I right to conclude that I may have to wait for certain objects and methods to appear in order to launch one office App from another?

I'm trying to link a number of Excel lines (customer interactions) one to one with OneNote pages.

I cannot find Office-js methods equivalent to [those used in this VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh377180(v=office.14).aspx). I looked in the [Office.js documentation](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/application) and see only a couple of methods.

It is perfectly possible that I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible with using Office.js. It's important to remember that each Web Add-in runs within its own sandbox and is essentially just a web app. It simply isn't possible for a Web Add-in to determine what other applications you have and remotely execute code against them (nor would you really want this if you consider the potential security risks that would open up).

What you *can* do however is leverage Microsoft Graph to interact with OneNote. So rather than having Excel drive OneNote over COM, you have your Web Add-in act as middleware between the current Excel Worksheet and a user's OneNote Notebook. You Add-in uses Office.js to communicate with the Worksheet and make REST calls to Microsoft Graph to interact the Notebook.

The first thing you'll need is an Access Token for the Excel user to use with Microsoft Graph. You can obtain this using the `getAccessToken()` method in Office.js. The steps for setting this up can be found at [Authorize to Microsoft Graph in your Office Add-in (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/authorize-to-microsoft-graph).

The second thing you'll need is to call Microsoft Graph. Assuming you want to keep things simple, I would use the [Microsoft Graph Client SDK for Javascript](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript#microsoft-graph-javascript-client-library) for this. You'll also want to take a look at the [OneNote API overview](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/integrate_with_onenote)
from Microsoft Graph's documentation.

There are also some samples in [OneNote's GitHub](https://github.com/OneNoteDev?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=graph&type=&language=). Although none of the samples are exactly what you're looking for, they may still provide some valuable insights into how the API works.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I was indeed barking up the wrong tree. Your swift and helpful reply much appreciated.